# HP Quality Center 12.20 Excel Uploader - Test Cases not Showing in Test Lab

Tags: excel, hp-quality-center

I have an excel sheet that I use to write test cases and use the HP ALM QC uploader Add-In for excel to import them to into Quality Center. All required fields are mapped (including some additional ones) and all data is validated before uploading.

I am able to upload successfully and see the test cases and steps all in the Test Plan. However, when I go to import them into a Test Set in Test Lab, the uploaded test cases don't show up (All other test cases do).

Am I missing a critical mapping or do I need to be a Local Administrator to be able to see the test cases when importing into Test Lab?

**Mapping File**

```
[Details]
task_name=mapping.tst
export_type=4
field_count=18
[FieldMapping]
mapping1=TS_USER_TEMPLATE_02;TEST;X
mapping2=TS_RESPONSIBLE;TEST;I
mapping3=TS_USER_TEMPLATE_06;TEST;AA
mapping4=TS_USER_TEMPLATE_03;TEST;AB
mapping5=TS_USER_TEMPLATE_04;TEST;Y
mapping6=TS_USER_TEMPLATE_05;TEST;Z
mapping7=TS_SUBJECT;TEST;AE
mapping8=TS_USER_TEMPLATE_07;TEST;AF
mapping9=TS_USER_TEMPLATE_08;TEST;AG
mapping10=TS_NAME;TEST;A
mapping11=TS_USER_TEMPLATE_10;TEST;AH
mapping12=TS_TYPE;TEST;J
mapping13=TS_DESCRIPTION;TEST;B
mapping14=DS_EXPECTED;STEP;F
mapping15=DS_DESCRIPTION;STEP;E
mapping16=DS_STEP_NAME;STEP;D
mapping17=TS_USER_TEMPLATE_09;TEST;AI
mapping18=TS_STATUS;TEST;AJ
```

.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming but instead about validation tools

Comment: @KevinDTimm ok...that's fine.. where on stack exchange can I ask about it?

Comment: stack may not have a forum - sorry

Comment: @KevinDTimm what else would the hp-quality-center tag be used for? There's no programming involved in that

Comment: I know nothing of HP Quality Centre but questions about tools used by programmers for programming are on-topic.  Validation tools would seem to qualify under that ruling, and this question may be on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the vales in the data sheet did not match 100% (CASE SENSITIVE) the required values by Quality Center.

**For example:** Test Type: Manual needed to be Test Type: MANUAL